# JSP file returns blank page

Tags: java, jsp, maven, tomcat

I'm a beginner in Java programming and tried to create a simple maven project in Java EE IDE. I use Apache Tomcat Server. I created a `jsp`  file in the webapp folder and my project compiled successfully.

However when opening it in the browser, it shows a blank page.
Here is the simple code of the jsp file.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello world
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show your directory structure (as in how the jsp file is stored)? What is your jsp file name? What does your web.xml look like? When you have a 'Java Server Page' (or JSP), it means that your tomcat server should be able to call some 'Java' code which will decide how to render the page. Without the web.xml and your project structure, it'll be hard for us to troubleshoot this issue. You can probably find more resources on the internet to find out who rendering of a JSP page works.

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/myapp/my.jsp`? Also the browser has a source view.

Comment: You said the browser has the source view(assumed you did "view page source"), did you still see the jsp directive. e.g. <%@ page language ... %>. If so, your set up is not correct. You are supposed to see HTML tags only.

Comment: 1. Do you run any file or project? 2.If you run project are you sure this page is home page?

Comment: I googled it but couldnt find any solution or i didnt understand. My JSP file is  stored in the Deployed Resources/webapp  as the name of index.jsp. About my web.xml file, its a kind of xml file includes some references such as a <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> @prabugp

Comment: For the googlers: This could happen if the JSP code raises an error. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/37320572/873282