# Blank page when server returns an error

Tags: jsp

I have a JSP servlet of format :

```
public void doGet(...)
{
    if(isRequestRegular(request))
    {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }
    else
    {
        response.setStatus(400);
        response.setContentLength(0);
    }
}
```

I would like to trigger the default error page stored in web browser, something like [this](http://www.ludovicdanteny.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/bell-fake-404-firefox.png). But Edge is the only browser that actually show something, all I get with Firefox and Chrome is a blank page, even when I specify a 404 status.

I am aware that you can set pre-defined error pages in **web.xml** but in this specific case I would rather not to.